# How to create knex request using MySQL syntax?

Tags: javascript, mysql, knex.js

In MySQL Workbench I have this:

```
USE my_db;
SELECT 
    transactions.created_at, price
FROM
    transactions
        JOIN
    transactions_items ON transactions.id = transactions_items.transaction_id
        JOIN
    store_items ON store_items.id = transactions_items.store_item_id;
```

As a result in workbench I get `created_at: price`. How can I create request to DB using knex syntax to get object `{created_at: price}`?

I was trying to use `knex.raw()`, but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const response = await knex('transactions')
        .join('transactions_items', 'transactions.id', '=', 'transactions_items.transaction_id')
        .join('store_items', 'store_items.id', '=', 'transactions_items.store_item_id')
        .select('transactions.created_at', 'price')
```